# Error on eclipse start up

Tags: eclipse

I am desperate.... no idea whats wrong. Yesterday it worked today it doesn't.

Here is the stacktrace from the logs, and it is generated before choosing the workspace:

```
!SESSION 2011-09-25 11:31:39.687 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
java.version=1.6.0_27
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=sk_SK
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product - clean
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product - clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-25 11:31:42.718
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Comment: This appears before or after choosing workspace?

Comment: Eclipse is on USB drive, so I do not know it can cause problem. But back to your question: It appears before choosing workspace...

Answer (score 0):

That is quite uncommon:  [bug 113596](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=113596) suggests some kind of issue with Windows (but not a definitive cause).
[This thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/525855/) suggests:

> Under the Eclipse installation directory is a folder named `...\configuration\.settings`.
>   If you move that folder to some temporary location, will Eclipse start? (it'll rebuild the folder and at least one of the prefs files if it starts).

---

Considering the Eclipse used here seems quite old:

```
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
```

It is not surprising that the [OP lyborko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226703/lyborko) reports:

> Nevetherless, I downloaded latest eclipse, and it works well...

Comment: No, I tried, but it throws an exeption again.... Nevetherless, I downloaded latest eclipse, and it works well... Thank you for interest :-)

Comment: @lyborko: excellent, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.